Can Kronecker Product Approximation (Nearest Kronecker Product) preserve invertibility?
Just as the title, I'm wondering about in Kronecker product approximation(Nearest Kronecker Product), if the original matrix is invertible, whether the two small matrices obtained after this approximation can still be invertible?
The origin question can be represented as:
Given $A\in  \mathbb R^{m\times n} $ with $m = m_1m_2$ and $n = n_1n_2$, find $B\in  \mathbb R^{m_1\times n_1}$ and $C\in \mathbb R^{m_2\times n_2}$ so
$\phi(B,C)$ = min $|| A- B\otimes C||_F$, where $F$ denotes Frobenius norm.
After find the matrix $B$ & $C$ with Van Loan's SVD method [1], i want to know if the Matrix $A$ is invertible, can the matrix $B$ & $C$ still be invertible? And how to prove it? What if $A$ is symmetric and invertible?
In fact, in Van's work, he proved that the approximation can preserve some structure, for example, symmetry and Non-negativity.And in some papers, i found they say "The Kronecker product SVD of Van Loan can yield invertible approximations in the square matrix case"([2] in section 3.3), but i didnot find the prove. Meanwhile, In my actual attempts, my approximate results are basically invertible.I have tried decomposing 100,000 random invertible 16x16 matrices into two 4x4 smaller matrices. In 100,000 approximations, each small matrix is invertible. Repeated attempts have also yielded the same results.
[1]Van Loan C., Pitsianis N., Approximation with Kronecker Products, Cornell University, Ithaca, NY, 1992
[2]Huhtanen M .Real linear Kronecker product operations[J].Linear Algebra and its Applications, 2006, 418(1):347-361.DOI:10.1016/j.laa.2006.02.020.

There doesn't seem to be any reason this should be true. You can work in reverse, choosing $B$ and $C$ to be, say, nilpotent. Then a generic perturbation of $B \otimes C$ will be invertible and you can choose this perturbation to be orthogonal to $B \otimes C$ with respect to the Frobenius inner product, and use that to define $A$. I haven't checked the details though.

I ask this question because in Van's work, he proved that the approximation can preserve some structure, for example, symmetry and Non-negativity. In fact in some papers, i found they say "The Kronecker product SVD of Van Loan can yield invertible approximations in the square matrix case"[2], but i didnot find the prove.  In fact , I don’t quite understand your idea. Could you please explain the details?
[2]Huhtanen M .Real linear Kronecker product operations[J].Linear Algebra and its Applications, 2006, 418(1):347-361.DOI:10.1016/j.laa.2006.02.020.
